# I got axios error and xhr failed loading error in my website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios, xmlhttprequest

I have created a resume builder website using react and node.js and I encountered this error on submitting the details. It starts loading the page and giving "xhr loading failed & Axios error"? how can I overcome this issue? and also I have entered openAI and it doesn't seem that it gives the error. I think Axios are the problem here and it stops the page from submitting details and loading the final result

Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import axios from "axios";

const Home = ({ setResult }) => {
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");
    const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState("");
    const [currentLength, setCurrentLength] = useState(1);
    const [currentTechnologies, setCurrentTechnologies] = useState("");
    const [headshot, setHeadshot] = useState(null);
    const [companyInfo, setCompanyInfo] = useState([{ name: "", position: "" }]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleAddCompany = () =>
        setCompanyInfo([...companyInfo, { name: "", position: "" }]);

    const handleRemoveCompany = (index) => {
        const list = [...companyInfo];
        list.splice(index, 1);
        setCompanyInfo(list);
    };
    const handleUpdateCompany = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const list = [...companyInfo];
        list[index][name] = value;
        setCompanyInfo(list);
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("headshotImage", headshot, headshot.name);
        formData.append("fullName", fullName);
        formData.append("currentPosition", currentPosition);
        formData.append("currentLength", currentLength);
        formData.append("currentTechnologies", currentTechnologies);
        formData.append("workHistory", JSON.stringify(companyInfo));
        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/resume/create", formData, {})
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.data.message) {
                    setResult(res.data.data);
                    navigate("/resume");
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
        setLoading(true);
    };
    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />;
    }else {

    
    return (
        <div className='app'>
            <h1>Resume Builder</h1>
            <p>Generate a resume with ChatGPT in few seconds</p>
            <form
                onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
                method='POST'
                encType='multipart/form-data'
            >
                <label htmlFor='fullName'>Enter your full name</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    required
                    name='fullName'
                    id='fullName'
                    value={fullName}
                    onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <div className='nestedContainer'>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor='currentPosition'>Current Position</label>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            required
                            name='currentPosition'
                            className='currentInput'
                            value={currentPosition}
                            onChange={(e) => setCurrentPosition(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor='currentLength'>For how long? (year)</label>
                        <input
                            type='number'
                            required
                            name='currentLength'
                            className='currentInput'
                            value={currentLength}
                            onChange={(e) => setCurrentLength(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor='currentTechnologies'>Technologies used</label>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            required
                            name='currentTechnologies'
                            className='currentInput'
                            value={currentTechnologies}
                            onChange={(e) => setCurrentTechnologies(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label htmlFor='photo'>Upload your headshot image</label>
                <input
                    type='file'
                    name='photo'
                    required
                    id='photo'
                    accept='image/x-png,image/jpeg'
                    onChange={(e) => setHeadshot(e.target.files[0])}
                />

                <h3>Companies you've worked at</h3>

                {companyInfo.map((company, index) => (
                    <div className='nestedContainer' key={index}>
                        <div className='companies'>
                            <label htmlFor='name'>Company Name</label>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                name='name'
                                required
                                onChange={(e) => handleUpdateCompany(e, index)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className='companies'>
                            <label htmlFor='position'>Position Held</label>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                name='position'
                                required
                                onChange={(e) => handleUpdateCompany(e, index)}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className='btn__group'>
                            {companyInfo.length - 1 === index && companyInfo.length < 4 && (
                                <button id='addBtn' onClick={handleAddCompany}>
                                    Add
                                </button>
                            )}
                            {companyInfo.length > 1 && (
                                <button
                                    id='deleteBtn'
                                    onClick={() => handleRemoveCompany(index)}
                                >
                                    Del
                                </button>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}

                <button>CREATE RESUME</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
                            }
};

export default Home;
```

index.js (server)

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const generateID = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10);

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 },
});

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: "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",
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const database = [];

const ChatGPTFunction = async (text) => {
  const response = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: "text-davinci-003",
    prompt: text,
    temperature: 0.6,
    max_tokens: 250,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 1,
    presence_penalty: 1,
  });
  return response.data.choices[0].text;
};

app.post("/resume/create", upload.single("headshotImage"), async (req, res) => {
  const {
    fullName,
    currentPosition,
    currentLength,
    currentTechnologies,
    workHistory,
  } = req.body;

  const workArray = JSON.parse(workHistory);
  const newEntry = {
    id: generateID(),
    fullName,
    image_url: `http://localhost:4000/uploads/${req.file.filename}`,
    currentPosition,
    currentLength,
    currentTechnologies,
    workHistory: workArray,
  };

  const prompt1 = `I am writing a resume, my details are \n name: ${fullName} \n role: ${currentPosition} (${currentLength} years). \n I write in the technolegies: ${currentTechnologies}. Can you write a 100 words description for the top of the resume(first person writing)?`;

  const prompt2 = `I am writing a resume, my details are \n name: ${fullName} \n role: ${currentPosition} (${currentLength} years). \n I write in the technolegies: ${currentTechnologies}. Can you write 10 points for a resume on what I am good at?`;

  const remainderText = () => {
    let stringText = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < workArray.length; i++) {
      stringText += ` ${workArray[i].name} as a ${workArray[i].position}.`;
    }
    return stringText;
  };

  const prompt3 = `I am writing a resume, my details are \n name: ${fullName} \n role: ${currentPosition} (${currentLength} years). \n During my years I worked at ${
    workArray.length
  } companies. ${remainderText()} \n Can you write me 50 words for each company seperated in numbers of my succession in the company (in first person)?`;

  const objective = await ChatGPTFunction(prompt1);
  const keypoints = await ChatGPTFunction(prompt2);
  const jobResponsibilities = await ChatGPTFunction(prompt3);

  const chatgptData = { objective, keypoints, jobResponsibilities };
  const data = { ...newEntry, ...chatgptData };
  database.push(data);

  res.json({
    message: "Request successful!",
    data,
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Resume from "./components/Resume";

const App = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState({});

    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Home setResult={setResult} />} />
                    <Route path='/resume' element={<Resume result={result} />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Loading.js

```
import React from "react";

const Loading = () => {
    return (
        <div className='app'>
            <h1>Loading, please wait...</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Loading;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the problem isn't in your react code, it's in `http://localhost:4000/resume/create`

this endpoint responds with an error, the reason the error is red in the console is that you're using `console.error(err)` instead of `console.log(err)`

You need to use a debugger for your endpoint first like https://insomnia.rest/
or
https://www.postman.com/